# How to get result in json from overpass-turbo?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

Is it possible to get result in JSON from http://overpass-turbo.eu/ (or directly from openstreetmap) ?

My request is:

```
(
  way
  (around:2000,55.693309807744484,21.151986122131348)
  [highway~"^(primary|secondary|tertiary|residential)$"]
  [name];
>;);out;
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to add this line in front of your statement:

```
[out:json]; ...
```

Comment: For more details refer to the [Overpass API documentation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API).

Comment: could you please show me a full query... i get only errors with it.

Comment: Just prepend *[out:json];* to your query.

Answer (score 2):

This is the query: http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json]%20;%20(%20way%20(around:2000,55.693309807744484,21.151986122131348)%20[highway~%22^(primary|secondary|tertiary|residential)$%22]%20[name];%20%3E;);%20out;

Yours was missing:
`[out:json]
;
<your part>`

and `%20` before `out;`

Comment: `%20` before `out;` is not needed (whitespace is ignored), the missing `[out:json]` was already mentioned in the other reply by MaM.

Comment: mille grazie - thank you